# statsmodels OLS t test calculation issue

Tags: regression, t-test, statsmodels

I notice statsmodels's OLS have different t value to a plain econometrics OLS. Below is an example:

```py
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
np.random.seed(1)
n = 40
x = np.random.normal(1, 1, n)
y = 8 * x + np.random.normal(0, 1, n)

mod = sm.OLS(y, x)
res = mod.fit(method='pinv')
print(res.params, res.tvalues) # [8.12308502] [72.25682714]

xx = np.sum(x*x)
xy = np.sum(x*y)
beta = xy / xx
resi = y - beta * x
resi_var = np.var(resi, ddof=1) / xx
tvalue = beta / np.sqrt(resi_var)
print(beta, tvalue) # 8.123085020673265 72.5022560464012
```

it is easy to see that the t value is off by 0.25. Is this some precision issue or statsmodels is using some special algo for calculation?

Comment: I can't seem to find where the t values are computed in the source code.  This may be something to ask the devs on github instead

Comment: in general, basic results like this are verified in statsmodels against R and Stata. There is no special case here that might cause numerical problems or where the definition might differ. So, check the user code first.

Comment: @Josef I can’t find the code to calculate t value. But the issue is OLS assume mean of residual 0 but np.var calculate the demeaned variance.